# XCode Swift Timer reloads in tableview when scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, nstimer

I run into a problem when i want to use a timer in an uitableview cell.
Everytime when i scroll to the bottom and then again up it resets the counter to its original value.

I know what the problem is.. the cell get's reloaded when scrolling back. But how can i achieve that the cell doesn't get reloaded when scrolling up and down so i can keep the origin cell. Any psuedo code would help.

My code looks likes this.

**FirstViewController.swift**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#bde8fb")
    parseXhr(offset,limit:limit)
    self.timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(FirstViewController.fireCellsUpdate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}





func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    // algemene cell gegevens
    let cell = self.tv.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    let separator = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 20))
    separator.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#bde8fb")
    cell.contentView.addSubview(separator)
    cell.photo.setBottomBorder("#bde8fb")
    cell.timeInterval = self.timercounter[indexPath.row]
    // load the image
    cell.photo.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit



    cell.photo.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:"\(Config.image_dir)\(imageUrlArray[indexPath.row])"),placeholderImage:  UIImage(named: Config.lazyLoadImage))
    // set the product name
    cell.veiling_title.text = productNameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.veiling_title.textAlignment = .Center
    return cell
}



func fireCellsUpdate() {
    let notification = NSNotification(name: "CustomCellUpdate", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)
}
```

And my **CustomCell.swift** looks like this

```
var timercounter = 0
@IBOutlet var veiling_title: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var photo: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var veilingSeconds: UILabel!

var timeInterval: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        self.veilingSeconds.text = "\(timeInterval)"
    }
}



func updateUI() {
    if self.timeInterval > 0 {
        self.timeInterval -= 1
    }
}




override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CustomCell.updateUI), name: "CustomCellUpdate", object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}




override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Comment: You need to update the model (`timercounter`) at the particular index path each time `timeInterval` changes to keep model and view in sync.

Comment: thanks!, do you have a code snippet for me? Must i update this in the FirstViewController.swift?

Comment: In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I would pass the index path (the row is sufficient) to the cell. Then you are able to update the counter in the `timercounter` array from the cell directly. If `timercounter` is value type don't forget to assign the changed value back to the array.

Comment: that doesn't work. in my controllers i added ` cell.timeInterval = [indexPath.row:seconds]`  and in my cell i do this ` var timeInterval: [Int:Int] = [0:0] {
        didSet {
            self.veilingSeconds.text = "\(self.timeInterval[self.indexPath])"
        }
    }`  but still nor results :x

Comment: I wrote an answer with a closure approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i finally got it working!

My issue was that i had to create multiple timers in a tableview. Everytime i scrolled up and down the timer was giving strange results (like seconds that aren't correct ; like overlapping labels and incorrect times). I created 2 times in my FirstViewControllers

1  A Timer to append all the seconds in the tableview, lets says GlobalTimerArray

2.And another timer what is running every seconds to decrement GlobalTimerArray

Then in my cellforRowAtIndexPath i do something like this:

```
  if !self.loadedCells.contains(indexPath.row) {
        self.loadedCells.append(indexPath.row)
        loadSeconds(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    } else {

       cell.timeInterval = self.saveSeconds[indexPath.row]
        print(secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(self.saveSeconds[indexPath.row]))

    }
```

and my viewdidload looks something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#bde8fb")

    socket.connect()
    self.timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(FirstViewController.fireCellsUpdate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    parseXhr(offset,limit:limit)
    self.secTimer  = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(FirstViewController.decSeconds), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.secTimer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}




func decSeconds()
{
      for index in 0..<self.saveSeconds.count {
        self.saveSeconds[index] -= 1
     }
}
```

I hope this helps someone, for me it was hard to understand, but perhaps it is because this is my first app what i am writing in Swift :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

In `FirstViewController` at the end of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` right before the `return` line insert

```
cell.callback = { (interval) in
  self.timercounter[indexPath.row] = interval
}
```

In `CustomCell` add a property

```
var callback : ((Int) -> ())?
```

and change `timeInterval`

```
var timeInterval: Int = 0 {
  didSet {
    self.veilingSeconds.text = "\(timeInterval)"
    callback?(timeInterval)
  }
}
```

The benefit of the callback is that it can capture the `timercounter` array and updates the value for the index path accordingly whenever `timeInterval` changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that still doesn;t work :(:(. I created a gist with your implementation. Perhaps you see something. I am very curious how the timer's dont get reloaded (spending 2 days now to figure this out).... 
[FirstviewController](https://gist.github.com/ermst4r/51410cfb427809b18ae34b3d646d977d)  

[Customcell.swift](https://gist.github.com/ermst4r/fb29c4ec3265ea6192b8d951fd162500)

Comment: Maybe the issue lies somewhere else. The callback is supposed to work